# Use Executors.newFixedThreadPool for only two threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

For a particular action, application creates two threads (doing different tasks) and main thread doesn't wait for it. Again for some cases, it can be only one thread too.

If I move this one to Executors.newFixedThreadPool(), does it make any difference? I understand Executors are doing thread management. It will be good for multi-threading scenarios.

But I want to know does it makes any small difference at least when two threads are changed to use executors? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ExecutorService`s are just a simpler way to handle executing things asynchronously. What small difference are you looking for? In regards to what?

Comment: Anything related to CPU utilization? something like that. I'm not expecting performance improvement as it is totally relay on tasks in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may results in better CPU utilization when u have a many threads and want to 
   execute few of them at a time, but if you have only two thread then I think it is 
   not beneficial to  use Executors.

from docs.oracle

Thread pools address two different problems: they usually provide improved performance when    executing large numbers of asynchronous tasks, due to reduced per-task invocation overhead, and they provide a means of bounding and managing the resources, including threads, consumed when executing a collection of tasks. Each ThreadPoolExecutor also maintains some basic statistics, such as the number of completed tasks.